# SwiftUI: what substitutes the Delegate protocol?

Tags: swift, architecture, swiftui

Let's consider one of the most basic flow available, where you have a view with data that is filled using other secondary views. i.e. Settings.

In the `Settings` view we have 2 items displayed:

```
SETTINGS
A - Pick a Color 
B - Pick a Country
```

When user taps one of the items, the App will present a new view that can be used to select a color or another view that can be used to select a country.

When the user is done with one of the selection views, the `Selection View` is closed and the selection is passed back to the `Settings` view that now displays the new info:

```
SETTINGS
A - Green 
B - Spain
```

With `delegates` and `protocols` we can easily implement this code just putting the `Settings` view as delegate for the `Colors` and the `Countries` view and implementing a specific method to receive user selection directly on the `Settings` view.

How can we achieve the same flow with `SwiftUI`? 
I'm reading about `@EnvironmentObject`, is this a case where `@EnvironmentObject` would work? how would you implement the case described above with `@EnvironmentObject`?

*Note: I've seen other similar questions but they were too specific for single cases. My question is broad and should generically apply to many differente cases.*

Answer (score 1):

I've found that a possible solution (instead of using `@EnvironmentObject`) would be to use `@Binding`.

For the **Settings View** I can have `selectedColor` and `selectedCountry` as `@State`

```
@State private var selectedColor:String = ""
@State private var selectedCountry:String = ""
```

Let's implement the **Color Selection View**. I can set a `bind` to a `color` variable this way:

```
@Binding var myColor:String = ""
```

Now if the value of `myColor` changes, since the variable is a Bind it will also change for the view that has the reference to this variable (in this case, the **Settings view**)

From the **Settings view** it would be enough to set the binding while presenting the `color view`.

```
NavigationLink(destination: ColorView(myColor: self.$selectedColor)) {
```

In my opinion this would be a good way to substitute the `Delegate` logic.